# What file name patterns does npm publish always ignore?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish) for the `npm publish` command says this regarding which files will be included in the package:

> If the file matches certain patterns, then it will never be included, unless explicitly added to the "files" list in package.json, or un-ignored with a ! rule in a .npmignore or .gitignore file

**What are those "certain patterns"?**

This seems very vague for technical documentation. Is the list of patterns documented anywhere (outside of the source code)?

The context that brought this up -- I was recently publishing a Javascript package with a directory named `src` nested several levels in the file structure. This directory was entirely omitted from the resulting published package. Renaming the directory caused it to be included on a subsequent try. There was not an allow list in the `package.json`, and there were no matching entries in '.npmingore'. It seems my `src` directory fell into this category of "certain patterns", but a cursory Google didn't turn up any further detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files matching the following patterns are always ignored when running `npm publish`:

- `.*.swp`
- `._*`
- `.DS_Store`
- `.git`
- `.gitignore`
- `.hg`
- `.npmignore`
- `.npmrc`
- `.lock-wscript`
- `.svn`
- `.wafpickle-*`
- `config.gypi`
- `CVS`
- `npm-debug.log`

This is documented in the [developer docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).